# Can you undo a lerna bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lerna, monorepo

I've run a lerna bootstrap --hoist. I now want to undo this and unlink all of the created symlinks. Is there a command to do this?

Comment: Do you mean to clean up node_modules from all packages created?

Comment: My understanding is that lerna bootstrap creates symlinks to dependent packages in node modules so dependencies dont have to be pulled externally. Will cleaning the node modules and doing an npm i get rid of these symlinks?

Comment: Yeah I think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lerna link (or bootstrap) will create symlinks either directly underneath a node_modules directory or, for packages with an [@-scoped name](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes), in a subdirectory with that name. Assuming your packages are all in `./packages/*`, Any symlinks directly underneath `./node_modules` or in `./packages/*/node_modules`. For instance, after bootstrap, lerna has created a couple symlinks to my creatively-named `@myscope/foo` package:

```
.
├── lerna.json
├── node_modules
│   └── @myscope
│       └── foo -> ../../packages/foo
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── packages
    ├── bar
    │   ├── node_modules
    │   │   └── @myscope
    │   │       └── foo -> ../../../foo
    │   └── package.json
    └── foo
        └── package.json
```

I can dig those out with find:

```sh
$ find . -type l -and \( -path './node_modules/*' -or -path './packages/*/node_modules/*' \)
./packages/bar/node_modules/@myscope/foo
./node_modules/@myscope/foo
```

This isn't perfectly selective because it could find symlinks that you created with `npm link`.

I can use `ls -l` to dump the source and the symlink target (vs. `readlink` which would just print the target):

```sh
$ find . -type l -and \( -path './node_modules/*' -or -path './packages/*/node_modules/*' \) -exec ls -l {} \;
lrwxrwxrwx 1 eric eric 12 janv.  4 09:46 ./packages/bar/node_modules/@myscope/foo -> ../../../foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 eric eric 18 janv.  4 09:45 ./node_modules/@myscope/foo -> ../../packages/foo
```

If you're feeling confident about selectivity, you can  `-exec rm {} \;` to remove them. It's not as good as a built-in undo, but at least it helps you see what lerna did.

Answer (score 1):

yes, run

```sh
lerna clean
```

Reference: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/clean#readme